# Kinesis data stream will not load to s3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to load an s3 bucket with my Kinesis data streams (at the closure of each stream) but I am receiving an error preventing me from doing this. Is there a way to do this with the java sdk?

Error -

```
Error: The website redirect location must have a prefix of 'http://' or 'https://' or '/'. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRedirectLocation; Request ID: ***; S3 Extended Request ID: ***; Proxy: null)
```

Method to load s3 bucket with stream -

```
public void uploadStreamToS3Bucket() {
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(String.valueOf(awsRegion))
            .build();
    try {
        String fileName = connectionRequestRepository.findStream() +".json";
        String bucketName = "downloadable-cases";
        String locationData = "arn:aws-us-***-1:kinesis:***:stream/" + connectionRequestRepository.findStream();
        s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, locationData));
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: its because you are using a arn as the redirect location, its supposed to be an actual url. i.e. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html also why are you trying to redirect to a kinesis arn?

Comment: @scigs I'm using it point towards individual Kinesis streams (basically storing the stream data on s3). I was trying to use arn for that, but honestly I'm not sure how to do this/what to point to.

Comment: You are using the OLD V1 Java AWS code.  V2 does not use the new keyword to create objects. Find updated V2 code here. https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2

Comment: @smac2020 I'll definitely look into that. Is what I'm trying even possible to do in this fashion? And where do I find my HTTP endpoint for an individual data stream?

Comment: You can certainty combine AMazon S3 and Kinesis functionality to place data into an Amazon S3 bucket. I like this use case and have identified this as a future example

Comment: I think you can use AWS Firehose and carry the data in the streams to an S3 sink? Might be a lot easier when we have multiple consumers reading off the same Kinesis stream.

Comment: @dashuser I did that, but unfortunately I can't seem to add the streamname to firehose in the PutRecordRequest (java sdk). At least I haven't found a way to. Is it possible?

Comment: Got it. There is no direct way that I know of to connect the firehose to the KDS stream. But how I usually do is -> have lambdas copy from KDS to Firehose :). Is that something that could work for you?